# How to make VLC going second desktop when going fullscreen?

Tags: macos, vlc-media-player, fullscreen, osx-el-capitan

Since the last Yosemite update (and by extension, El Capitan), VLC doesn't go on a second desktop anymore when I press the fullscreen button on the upper left of the window as it used to do :/

Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: It ought to fullscreen on whichever screen it's currently on

Comment: I know, and I'd like it to open on a second screen

Comment: then drag it to the 2nd screen before you fullscreen it

Comment: Haha, I want it to be automatic, otherwise that's easy  
Thank you for your help

Comment: It ought to be, the second time you do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@justsomerandomdude has provided the good answer to this problem.
Quoting them:

> *I just found the fix to this. Basically you just have to go in to the settings and select "show all" in the bottom left, expand "Interface", expand "main interfaces", go into macosx and select "use native full screen mode" (or something along those lines, using different localization here).*

Comment: Have to restart VLC a few times to make sure this kicks in. Can check by e.g. toggling dark mode to see if it changes. Once it does, the new full screen setting should work.

Answer (score 5):

Having the same weird issue here. What has proven to kind of work for me on El Cap is using the green fullscreen button on the top left corner first (creates basically a black desktop with VLC controls in it) and then CMD+F twice when in fullscreen VLC (puts the content inside and the controls on top). To get it back to windowed mode CMD+F, switch to another Desktop, back to fullscreen VLC and click the green fullscreen button again... A bit fiddly and certainly annoying. it seems like the VLC interface doesn't respect the way Mac OS handles fullscreen right now. Anyway, I hope that workaround works for you. You could still create a second desktop like the commenters before me suggested, would probably be easier.

Comment: I just found the fix to this. Basically you just have to go in to the settings and select "show all" in the bottom left, expand "Interface", expand "main interfaces", go into macosx and select "use native full screen mode" (or something along those lines, using different localization here).

Comment: "use native full screen mode" is the right answer

Comment: @justsomerandomdude could you answer properly (i.e. not in a comment)? So that I can mark your answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just go into Preferences, click the video tab and in the Fullscreen video device choose the screen you want VLC to be in.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T1Yg.png)

Answer (score 1):

Head over to Videos -> Full screen video devices and select resolution of the screen you wish to maximize to.

Answer (score 1):

Go to video settings > use native fullscreen mode

Answer (score 1):

After enable `native fullscreen mode`, you should also `⌘ + q` to fully quit the vlc for loading the setting. (I can't add comments due to lack of reputation)

Answer (score 0):

Go to preferences, click on video tab and unselect the Black screens in Fullscreen mode.
[See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rInA.png)

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, @justsomerandomdude has already provided the answer. This answer contains a screenshot displaying the solution.

[image]